# Ссылки на справочную литературу по пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

В этом году сдаю ЕГЭ. Знаю почти все, что надо, но предложения - это мое слабое место. Скиньте, пожалуйста, ссылку на источник, где подробно рассказывается о простых и сложных предложениях, видах придаточных и так далее. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для всех заданий очень хорош "Задачник"  Егораевой (именно для подготовки к ЕГЭ). Особенно если Вам нужно подготовиться именно к части А и В, а не погрузиться в тонкости русской пунктуации. В ЕГЭ проверяются базовые знания по пунктуации. "Задачник" хорош  тем, что ориентирован именно на типы предложений, рассматриваемых на экзамене.  Не знаю, есть ли он  в он-лайн версии. Зато есть ее же(Егораевой) презентации. Одна из них - "Ловушки ЕГЭ".

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать [***грамоту.ру***](http://gramota.ru) как хороший сайт, на котором можно найти почти любую интересующую вас информацию про русский язык. Есть один недостаток: если вам надо просто натаскаться на тесты (а не подробно, как вы выразились, рассмотреть пунктуацию), то на этом сайте слишком много лишней информации, которая вам не пригодится для сдачи экзаменов (зато пригодится для общего развития, если оно вам, конечно, надо).
На Яндексе есть такой раздел, как [***ЕГЭ по русскому языку***](http://ege.yandex.ru/russian/), там можно, так скажем, набить руку на тесты.
Для представления о пунктуации вообще советую полистать Розенталя. Конечно, лучше взять книжку в библиотеке, но её можно и в интернете найти (например, [***здесь***](http://www.alleng.ru/d/rusl/rusl57.htm), но я не отвечаю за этот сайт, так как мне выдал его Гугл). Кстати, Гугл выдаёт достаточно ссылок по запросам о пунктуации. Но я бы вам посоветовал взять в библиотеке любой справочник и учить по нему.

Для начала я бы посоветовал почитать про вводные слова и посмотреть их список (например, [***неплохая таблица***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2N9Y.jpg)).
 Всего пару раз прочитав наглядные примеры, понимая их значение, можно с лёгкостью определять их в тексте. Потом рассмотреть союзы и их виды и так далее по справочнику.